# Did Dumbledore know that Snape was bullying Harry and Neville?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, severus-snape

Snape is a triple agent. He sided with Dumbledore because Voldemort killed Lily, the only person who Snape loved and cared. Snape was a spy among the Death Eaters and was giving information to Dumbledore. Why is Snape always bullying Harry and Neville,  since Snape has a reason to protect Harry? **Did Dumbledore know this?** If so, how did Dumbledore react to this?

Comment: Triple agent? He pretends to work for Voldemort and Dumbledore against each other, which would be double. Since he worked as a spy for Dumbledore first, he wouldn't even be a redoubled agent.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115357/29220 this answer in particular is what your looking for

Comment: That question is about Snape being unfair to Harry/Gryffindor? But in this question, I'm asking if Dumbledore know that Snape is a Bully to Harry and Neville.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 answer of dupe "Q: Why does Professor Dumbledore allow Professor Snape to be so nasty to the students (especially to Harry, Hermione, and Neville)?
JKR: "Dumbledore believes there are all sorts of lessons in life ... horrible teachers like Snape are one of them!" (Yahooligans! chat, 2000)"   That is exactly what your question is asking about.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 your asking a smaller scope question when a larger scope question already exists and answers your question perfectly.